# How do I get magit to run: git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master ? (gerrit)

Tags: helm, magit, git

Gerrit has a magical reference (refs/for/master) that when you push to submits your commit to the code review system. I haven't been able to figure out how to get magit to push to this. I'm not sure if this is a limitation or if it's my inability to figure out the interface. On the command line this command works:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Using magit if I try to push to a branch, I am forced to choose from a list (I am also using helm), but this option isn't available. If I manually type it in, magit instead runs:

```
git … push -v origin master\:refs/heads/HEAD\:refs/for/master
```

Which fails. If I tell it I want to push an explicit refspec it makes me choose from explicit list that only has "origin" in it, and this time I am unable to manually type in my own choice.